# Speakers are playing music, but voices are muffled

Tags: windows-7, audio, speakers

I was messing around on a game and I fiddled with the RealTek Audio Manager and with the actual speakers themselves (I moved them forward a bit, I thought I felt a yank but nothing came out). After I did, when I tried to listen to a video or a movie on my computer, the background music would be PERFECT but the voices are completely muffled and only when you put max volume you can kind of hear the muffled voice.

I tried resetting the RealTek Audio Manager 'Environment' and 'Equalizer' back to default but nothing happened. I tried looking at the back of my speaker's chords but they seem to be in place.

I don't know what else to do.
Is it because I didn't check if the chords were in correctly? I did follow them through and I'm SURE that they're in place.

Comment: Sounds like you pulled out your center channel speaker.

Comment: did you enable "karaoke mode"?

Comment: Try with different speakers (or even headphones) to narrow down the suspects.